# why std::is_integral considers bool type as integral

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits

In C++ type traits
`std::is_integral<T>::value` returns true even if T is bool which is correct as per its description.

But if bool is  a different type than other integral types, why its considered as integral type in this case?
why we don't have a separate std::is_boolean type trait?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;

    std::cout << std::is_same<int, bool>::value << ' '; // ~ false
    std::cout << std::is_same<unsigned int, bool>::value << ' '; // ~ false
    std::cout << '\n';
    std::cout << std::is_integral<bool>::value << ' '; // ~ true
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can test bool via `is_same`. Why add special trait for bool? How bool is different from other integrals? It's just different number of bits.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `bool` is an integral type. "Integral type" != same as `int` / `unsigned int`, which you seem to be checking.

Comment: Why should `bool` not be an integral type? `long` and `char` are also integrals types distinct from `int`. Why don't we have special traits `is_char` or `is_long`? Being an integral type and being an `int` are two different things.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number sadly in mathematics, it is, which is probably a more commonly known definition. This really should've been called `std::is_fundamental/essential` or something even more clear instead as "integral" in programming is ambiguous, as C++ has integral types, but also integral types. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression#Integral_constant_expression

Comment: @Kaihaku " C++ has integral types, but also integral types. " ? Did you mean integral types and integer types?

Comment: [basic.fundamental](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.fundamental#def:integral_type): "Types bool, char, wchar_­t, char8_­t, char16_­t, char32_­t, and the signed and unsigned integer types [...] are collectively termed integral types. A synonym for integral type is integer type."

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number integral types are integer types, but integral types also aren't integer types. English is sometimes just as terrible as C++.

Comment: Please don't pull the question apart. `boolean` is not considered an integral type in Java. That goes some way in my mind to giving the question credibility.

Comment: The trait is unnecessary from a library perspective; there is exactly one boolean type, and `std::is_same` already exists. If you feel a need for it, add `template<typename T> using is_boolean<T> = std::is_same<T, bool>;`.

Answer (score 4):

It's an integral type so it can appear in Integral Constant Expressions. This is quite important when it comes to writing templates - `true` and `false` are commonly used as non-type template parameters.

Answer (score 0):

`bool` is a one bit integral type.  There are many integral types -- `int`, `long`, `long long`, `std::uint32_t`.

The fact that `bool` is an integral type goes back to the start of C++ and even back to C, where `1 == 0` returns an integer.

If you want to detect `bool`, use `is_same<T, bool>`.

There could easily be a language much like C++ where `bool` isn't integral.  But that isn't C++.